# Beamer frames show a white line on top

Tags: beamer

I want to make a presentation with the `beamer` class. However, there appears an annoying white horizontal line on top of all pages except the first one. The line thickness is only about 1mm, but it looks ugly anyway. The bug can be seen in this short example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\RequirePackage{type1cm} % font

\useoutertheme{miniframes} % colored top to show the white line
\useinnertheme{default} 
\usecolortheme{albatross} % dark color to show the white line   

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} % no white line
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{section1} % white line
\begin{frame}{test}
  test
\end{frame}

\section{section2} % white line
\begin{frame}{test2}
  test2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like to remove this white line.

Comment: I can't see any white line there

Comment: In Sumatra PDF that is usually the case but Adobe Acrobat does not show that line. Hence, it's probably a reader issue.

Comment: For me, Adobe Acrobat Reader as well as Ocular show this line. By the way, I use beamer.cls 2011/09/12 development version 3.12.

Comment: I've only Adobe Acrobat on my computer (v. 10.1.2). I'm using the same version of `beamer` as you do.

Comment: Adobe reader 9.4.2 and kpdf 0.5.4 (I know, superold) both don't show a white line.

Comment: I am using Acrobat Reader 9.4.7 (on linux), so probably the error is somewhere else. I have no clue though.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely the reader. Comparing TeXworks' built-in viewer (0.4.3 r858), Sumatra 1.9, and Adobe Reader 10.1.2 on the same PDF:

[image]

Though I don't think it makes any difference for the question:

1. TeXworks and Sumatra were zoomed to 800%, and Adobe Reader to 700%. They look comparable in terms of how high the blue bands are, but I'm not sure why the percentages differ.
2. I'm seeing the white line on frame 1 as well.

Comment: Thank you for these efforts. After experimenting, I am pretty sure though that it is **not caused by the reader**. I built the code above on another machine and looked at the resulting pdf on my machine - no white bar was visible. When I build it on my machine, the white bar comes visible. And only on page 2 and the following.

Comment: Try to end all lines by a percent sign to make all the end-lines and leading whitespace removed. It could have helped.

Comment: Good idea, but no change. That's how it looks for me, by the way: http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/520/presentationlu.png

Comment: Also, on the same PDF as shown above, Sumatra reads the frame size as  5.04x3.79 inches, while Adobe reads it as 5.04x3.78 inches -- there are definitely differences in how the readers interpret the same PDF.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not the reader but a problem with pgf and beamer. It was solved some time ago, so update both packages.

This issue was reported [here](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/120) a [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3023390&group_id=142562&atid=752792)

Comment: I still have that problem after updating