# Getting shaded headline flush with top of slide with outertheme tree in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm using the following code (roughly) to install a left-right shaded background behind a [beamer](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) headline. The contents of the headline is set using the `outertheme` `tree`. The shading method is based roughly on that for `Singapore`. The problem is that I have a line of light green at the very top of the slide, whereas I would like the dark green to go all the way to the top.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\definecolor{acol}{rgb}{.5,1,.5}
\definecolor{bcol}{rgb}{.1,.6,.2}
\colorlet{bcol1}{bcol!25!black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=acol,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=acol,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=acol,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line head}{bg=bcol1}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=bcol1}
\makeatletter
\useoutertheme{tree}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{beamer@headfade}{\dimexpr5.4375ex+3pt}
{%
  color(0cm)=(bcol1);
  color(\paperwidth)=(acol)%
}
\addtoheadtemplate{\vskip 3pt\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}\vskip\dimexpr -3pt-10.875ex}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

  \title{Title}
  \section{A Section}
  \subsection{A Subsection}

  \begin{frame}{A Frame}{A Subframe}
    Some text
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Presumably I've miscalculated or used the wrong values somewhere but every time I push something, something or other pushes back and I just can't seem to get it right. (Probably because I'm mesmerised, as usual, by the maze of `beamer`'s code.)

Any hint would be much appreciated!

[image: light green peeking at very top]

Comment: No time to dig in for a proper answer now but if you use `\addtoheadtemplate{\vskip 2.5pt...` the upper line goes to the top: [picture here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KOZHR.png)

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks very much! That works perfectly. If you would like to write a proper answer (ideally explaining how to figure out the right value), I'd be happy to accept/up-vote it. (I'm hoping to accept an answer which explains but I'm happy to up-vote an answer which just works in the meantime!)

Comment: @HarishKumar I'm now even more puzzled. When I used these slides today, it turns out there is a light vertical line at the far left of the slide. So clearly I'm missing something here! However, I cannot see it in Okular at all.

Comment: There's a question related to this somewhere... I'm almost sure I've seen this issue asked about but I can't remember... If I zoom in and then return to fit-page view, I see the pale vertical line - or, more, a wide rectangle - for a moment before the shading covers it over. Something like this came up - somebody asked. If anybody has a clue where that question is, please let me know!

Comment: @HarishKumar Do you think my question is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42149/39222? I'm especially suspicious now it turns out I also get a vertical line with Adobe Reader on Windows but not (except for a second) with Okular on GNU/Linux.

Comment: Looks so. I forgot yesterday. Later today when I get some time, I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I get an error with the MWE you provided. It's given in this line, saying that `\dimexpr` can not be used in vertical mode:

```
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{beamer@headfade}{\dimexpr5.4375ex+3pt}
```

I just removed it, and it works for me (there's no line at the top):

```
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{beamer@headfade}{5.4375ex+3pt}
```

---

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\definecolor{acol}{rgb}{.5,1,.5}
\definecolor{bcol}{rgb}{.1,.6,.2}
\colorlet{bcol1}{bcol!25!black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=acol,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=acol,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=acol,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line head}{bg=bcol1}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=bcol1}
\makeatletter
\useoutertheme{tree}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{beamer@headfade}{5.4375ex+3pt}
{%
  color(0cm)=(bcol1);
  color(\paperwidth)=(acol)%
}
\addtoheadtemplate{\vskip 3pt\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}\vskip\dimexpr -3pt-10.875ex}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

  \title{Title}
  \section{A Section}
  \subsection{A Subsection}

  \begin{frame}{A Frame}{A Subframe}
    Some text
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's odd. It compiles fine here. Moreover, removing it does not resolve the issue for me. I get exactly the same visual result.

Comment: Just added a picture and the full code I've used. I'm using MiKTeX and compiling with `pdflatex`. I don't know if that could make the difference.

Comment: I'm using `pdflatex` but I'm using TeX Live. I can compile either way. With exactly the same results either way. I don't doubt it is different for you, but this is not, unfortunately, of help to me. Thanks anyway.